# VB: Make webbrowser1 click a button on a webpage

Tags: vb.net

Well, I guess title says most of it. I already know how to click a button within a browser but the code doesn't work on this pacific button. I hope this code is allowed on here, sorry if it's not...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button3.Enabled = True
    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        'AMF Email
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").InnerText textbox1.text

        'AMF Password
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = textbox2.text

        'AMF Login Button
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Login" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next

    'Navigates to FB likes to begin the process
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://addmefast.com/free_points/facebook_likes")
    Button2.PerformClick()

End Sub
```

Okay so all this code works perfectly, but now I want it to click the "Like" button on this link: http://addmefast.com/free_points/facebook_likes

However, I can not find the correct value. Can anyone help get the correct value for the "Like" button on that page?

VB2012

When I try to "Inspect Element" on the button, this is all it shows;

```
    <div class="btn3">
        Like
    </div>
```

Comment: hey i dont really have the answer.. but there is an addmefast automated script for firefox imacros.. check em out

Comment: @Bone Thanks, and I have it. But I'm trying to make a multi-threaded safe from anti-ban with webrequests...After I make it successfully do a task I'm requesting. Macros to slow + detected.

Comment: :o.. give me the app too xD

Comment: this is what imacros uses to click the like button, 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:*&&VALUE:Like

Comment: Nah none of those worked :( Thanks everyone for trying though I'll figure it out in the end lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do this:

```
For Each elem as HtmlElement in WebBrowser1.Document.All
    If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "btn3" Then
        elem.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

Sorry if there is any mistakes here. I am use to using an IDE for my code...
I hope this helps,

Rodit